# Как передать большую конфигурацию через docker-compose в скрипт

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

Я знаю два способа записи конфигурации в `docker-compose.yml`:

- `.env` файл
- напрямую через `environment`

Переданные параметры доступны через окружение.

Сейчас же нужно передать довольно большую, структурированную конфигурацию в NodeJS. Для этого подошел бы JSON или YML. Но как это передать?

Пробую:

- кодировать как query, затем через `querystring.decode()` декодировать, но чувствую, что какое-то тупиковый путь
- монтирование тома мне совсем не нравится

Какой бест-практис способ выбрать?

### Чем не нравится монтирование тома

1. Конфигурация размазывается по трем местам: `.env` файл (нельзя перезаписать при "up"), `environment` (можно перезаписать так: `RUN_TESTS=on docker-compose up test-compose`), монтированный том. Хочется собрать в каком-то более-менее единственном месте.
2. Есть переменные, которые нужно передавать в JSON (NodeJS), и в виде переменной окружения - в другой контейнер (Exim), Exim "не понимает" JSON

Comment: почему не нравится монтирование тома? нормальный способ

Comment: @IvanVovk, обновил вопрос

Comment: посмотрите в сторону разворачивания локального гитлаба, там в настройках CICD можно указывать различные переменные, в том числе и json-файлы, чтобы использовать их далее в контейнерах. https://community.vscale.io/hc/ru/community/posts/115003739845